# apple finder webdav client puts file with no content

Tags: .net, http, webdav

I am creating a webdav server to be able to easily add/(re)move files to our backoffice software.
So I am also implementing the PUT command, and that works OK if I use Windows Explorer to create files.
However when I use the Mac OS X Finder (with the help of Transmit, but that makes no difference) to PUT a file to the server, I get no content.
I configured Fiddler as a reverse proxy, and that shows me the following request:

```
PUT http://localhost:15001/WebDav/test.txt HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: TransmitFSHelper/1.0.2 neon/0.29.3
Connection: TE
TE: trailers
Host: localhost:49416
Content-Length: 0
```

It does not send any content.
I have read something about 'trailers', chunked encoding etcetera, but don't know wat to respond to the client to get him to send the contents of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a new file is created (fopen('bla','w')) first an empty file will appear on the disk. This is why you're seeing the initial request with a 0-byte file. After that a program may append to the file, but this will be a separate request.

So treat the 0-byte file as a correct one, and send back 201 Created. You should see a secondary request after that.

*however* it is true that sometimes clients (such as Finder) will use chunked encoding in the HTTP request. I implemented a webdav server in PHP, and it's simply not working when using FastCGI and Finder, the server must run on apache with mod_php for it to work.

So if the chunked request fails or succeed depends on your stack, I wouldn't know with .NET. But at the very least you should be able to see 2 requests going to the server, rather than one. The chunked encoding issue is separate from that.